# What planet is Mace Windu from?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Which planet is Mace Windu from?
Every Jedi is from a planet.
There are MANY examples, but I can't list them off the top of my head.
Anyhow, I just wanna know Mace Windu and his origins.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Man, you gotta love the Samuel L. Jackson love on here <3

Comment: He is from planet "What". They speak English on planet What.

Answer (score 8):

**Disney/Full Canon**

According to the game [*Star Wars: Journeys*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Journeys:_Beginnings), Windu is from [Haruun Kal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Haruun_Kal).

**EU/Legends Canon**

Prior to the canon purge, this same fact was established in the book [Shatterpoint](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shatterpoint_%28novel%29).

> *I [Windu] was born on Haruun Kal. Far back in the highland.*
>
> *I am a full-blooded Korun.*

Comment: *"Haruun Kal" ain't no planet I've ever heard of. They speak Galactic Basic Standard on Haruun Kal?* ***Galactic Basic Standard, nerf-herder, do you speak it?***

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr *"You know what they call a Quarter Pounder on Alderaan?"*

Comment: @drrdrizzle They don't call it a Quarter Pounder with cheese?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Nah, they don't call it nuthin', man. Alderaan done blew up.